# Dell Inspiron 15 5559 hangs at shutdown, wierd start ups

Tags: sound, dell, shutdown, programming, c++

I just bought a new Dell machine. It's awesome! It has a 6th Gen Intel i5, Radeon M335 (4gb ddr3), 8gb of ram< win 10. Nothing special, but still quite good.

Anyways I wanted to install Ubuntu on it as I am a CS student currently learning C++. I really like how Ubuntu feels like and since I am not doing any of "real" programming for now (e.d. creating real software apps and so on..) I like to play around gedit and than just compile it in terminal.

Anyways, I did install Ubuntu. Problems started arising as soon as I did. After I finished installing it for the first time, I heard a crackling noise in the speakers. I tought that was strange, checked online, wrote a few lines in Terminal and that was solved.

Than the major problem I had was that I couldn't reboot or shut down the laptop normaly. It woud hang at shutdown with a big list in front of me of some adresses. After I checked online and couldn't find anything that could resemble my issues I reinstalled it and started from scratch. The same problem repeated itself again and again. I ended up installing it a couple of times and at he end I gave up and I deleted it.

Yet I am seeking right now the help of the people of this community as I want to program really really bad in the Ubuntu environment!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using a Virtual machine instead, if direct installation doesn't work.

Comment: Direct installation did work (in some way I could say). The problem begin after it. And I have no idea what may cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Dell 5559 running Ubuntu 14.04 that hung on shutdown.  The problem was between Intel Skylake Graphics and the Linux Kernel [3.13] that came with Ubuntu 14.04.  Upgrading to Kernel 4.3 fixed the problem.

Instructions for upgrading to Kernel 4.3: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/11/linux-kernel-4-3-released/. Download and install the three deb files from the provided link.

I could see the problem by running `dmesg` in terminal.  At the end of the readout was several pages of...

```
[   20.904526] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 3 stalled for more than 13500msec
[   20.904531] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000017 last fence id 0x000000000000003c on ring 3)
```

Running `lspci -nn | grep VGA` showed me that the grapics card is Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics.

Comment: Hey Man! That's it! Thank you soooo much! You did it!

Anyways, I am experiencing another issue right now, after upgrading to kernel 4.3. It's diagonal screen flickering... do you know anything about that? Have you experienced it after the kernel upgrade? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I get the flicker as well.  It only occurs below a diagonal line running from upper right to lower left.  It happens when scrolling.  When I boot using the old kernel the flicker is not there, so the problem is with the new kernel.  It happens only occasionally, it is not sever, and does not interfere with anything so I am not going to worry about it.  Skylake is new and there may be some kinks that still need to be worked out.  The flicker will probably be gone with the next kernel or driver update.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what's been happening. Man, I guess Ubuntu needs to update it's support. Many have been complaining about the Ubuntu on Skylake. Hopefully we are going to get the update soon.

Just another quick question. So after what I did here, the Skylake is now main GPU on my system? Radeon is not used at all?